# AngularJS e2e test difference between select (dropdown), input radio, input checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, drop-down-menu, radio-button

There is not a consistent way of e2e testing different form attributes in AngularJS. I know AngularJS updated their e2e testing with Protractor, but for everybody that still uses the old version, I would like to know the difference between:

**Select items:**

1a. Selecting an item from a select (dropdown) list

1b. Selecting a radio button

1c. Checking a checkbox

**Check if selected:**

2a. Check if dropdown is selected

2b. Check if a radio button is selected

2c. Check if a checkbox is checked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace two variables in all examples:

- replace "`modelName`" with the name of your model
- replace "`value`" with the value of your form attribute

**Select item:**

1a. Selecting item from a select (dropdown) list:

`select('modelName').option('value');`

1b. Selecting item in a radio button:

```
input('modelName').select('value');
```

1c. Checking a checkbox:

```
input('modelName').check();
```

**Check if selected:**

2a. Check item in a select (dropdown) list:

```
expect(input('modelName').val()).toEqual(value);
```

2b. Check item in a radio button

```
expect(element('input[ng-model="modelName"]:checked').val()).toEqual(value);
```

2c. Check item in a checkbox

```
expect(element('input[ng-model="modelName"]').prop('checked')).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: It says @ val not  a function, I guess the new version has a diff syntax, any idea how to do it for  a radio button

Answer (score 1):

For checking if a radio button is checked, I've been using:
`element(by.id('radiobutton')).getAttribute('checked').then(function(value) {
      expect(value).toBe('true'); // value is 'true' if checked, and is null if not checked
 });`